# Docker alpine image fails to build because of HDF5 and tables

Tags: python, linux, docker, hdf5, alpine-linux

I am building a Docker image based on alpine linux. During build I get the error when installing `tables` that I have no local `hdf5` installation.

To solve this I tried to install `hdf5` as recommended in various posts:

- [`pip install tables` fail with ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063064/)
- [Cannot install h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778299/)
- https://github.com/freqtrade/freqtrade/issues/4162
- https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/219

Yet, even if I install `hdf5` package in my Docker container the same error occurs (I also tried `hdf5-dev` package but this includes SciPy and I don't want SciPy since it takes ages to build).

Note that I don't even know why tables is installed, or let's say which dependency installs tables. So as a solution I'd be happy to remove the dependency that installs tables, if I don't need it. Yet most of my requirements in my requirements.txt I do need. Most of all I need `pandas`, `matplotlib` and `numpy`.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.14

RUN apk add --no-cache --update-cache hdf5

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client \
  ## Needed for sphinx https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/issues/1747
  && apk add make \
  ## Needed for postgis
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    g++ \
    gdal-dev \
    geos-dev \
    json-c-dev \
    libtool \
    libxml2-dev \
    proj-dev \
    protobuf-c-dev \
    graphviz \
    ttf-freefont

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base

COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN python -m pip install -r /requirements/local.txt
```

Also note that my dockerfile was working perfectly fine until maybe 4 weeks ago. Then it started throwing this error. I would be happy to completely change the Docker image as long as I can install `pandas`, `matplotlib` and `numpy` in it.

What I also tried:

- Pulling image `python:3.8`
- Changing alpine version
- Not using --virtual and removing .build-deps

The full error:

> Downloading tables-3.6.1.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /usr/local/bin/python -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-g7jsy3s2/tables_ade9c044a3584a07b883ac519dd110db/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-g7jsy3s2/tables_ade9c044a3584a07b883ac519dd110db/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-geym875g
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-g7jsy3s2/tables_ade9c044a3584a07b883ac519dd110db/
> Complete output (12 lines):
> * Using Python 3.9.7 (default, Aug 31 2021, 19:01:35)
> * USE_PKGCONFIG: True
> /tmp/H5closelwxa646a.c: In function 'main':
> /tmp/H5closelwxa646a.c:2:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'H5close' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
> 2 |     H5close();
> |     ^~~~~~~
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
> You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
> library can be found by setting the `HDF5_DIR` environment
> variable or by using the `--hdf5` command-line option.
> ----------------------------------------
> WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/32/847ee3f521aae6a0be380d923a736162d698586f444df1ac24b98c65025c/tables-3.6.1.tar.gz#sha256=49a972b8a7c27a8a173aeb05f67acb45fe608b64cd8e9fa667c0962a60b71b49 (from https://pypi.org/simple/tables/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: "HDF5 headers and library" -- those are in the "-dev" package. Note that you can usually remove this package and any of the deps it pulls in after building, in order to not waste too much space.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Ahh I understand. Thank you! But do you think it is possible somehow to install the dev-package without scipy? To save also time on build?

Comment: I don't know. I know in Debian, you have "recommended" packages that are by default installed along even though they are not strict dependencies. Maybe that is the case here, too? Also, concerning build speed, making best use of Docker's build cache using multiple build stages is also a possibility.